# JavaScript get text

Tags: javascript, php

I want to list the values from a table in db that contains more than one word, but the JS function I use just gets the first word.

Say original value is "word1 word2", the value listed is just "word1"

`$row['nama']` is the variable I list from the db.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
    function updateTextArea() {     
       var allVals = [];
       $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {

           allVals.push((i!=0?"\r\n":"")+ $(this).val());
       });
       $('#isi').val(allVals).attr('rows',allVals.length) ;
       }
    });//]]> 
    </script>

  <textarea class="textfield" id="isi" name="isi" rows="2"></textarea>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes" class="taglist" style="display: none;">
<?php
    include("koneksi.php");
    $query = "SELECT nama FROM user";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' value=".$row['nama'].">".$row['nama']."</label>";  /
    }
?>
```

How do I fix this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your actual output and what is your expected output?

Comment: can you post your mysql table structure and the query you are using to pull the data? not sure how to answer your question without that information.

Comment: @chiliNUT i just edited the question. output i hope is : Word1 Word2. But this case give output : Word1. Thqnks

Comment: You never call `updateTextArea`. Where is `showCheckboxes` defined? `mysql_` functions are deprecated for years now. Why still use them?